# "import tensorflow" terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Tags: tensorflow

An `import tensorflow` statement triggers the following error:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.dylib locally
"import tensorflow" terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, CUDA creates `libcuda.dylib`, but TensorFlow tries to load
`libcuda.1.dylib`. To fix the problem, create a symbolic link between
`libcuda.dylib` and `libcuda.1.dylib`. For example, if CUDA is installed
in `/usr/local/cuda`, issue the following `ln` command:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.1.dylib
```